# Remove watermarks from pdf file

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to remove annoying watermarks from `pdf` file in Linux?

For example, every page contains text

> This file was merged by application XY.

Answer (score 2):

If the PDF isn't encrypted, this might be *possible* but can be very hard. I know of no application that does that, so you will have to create your own using a [library for PDF manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210029/821436). Of course this requires knowledge of the PDF standard.